# how to pass scandinavian charaters like ö and ä in XML encoded messages in loadrunner?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

Is there any way to pass scandinavian charaters ö and ä in XML encoded messages in loadrunner?
I have a scenario where, i need to pass XML containing words with ö and ä then encode the message, after it reaches end system it get decoded and words like

Henkilötunnus becomes Henkil�tunnus

Vahinkopäivä become Vahinkop�iv�

which is giving error. any solution to this?

Comment: The XML should be in UTF-8 encoding and the text filled as UTF-8. You are seeing output in a non-UTF-8 encoding that cannot represent the special char. It is not even the HTTP default Latin-1, ISO-8859-1.

Comment: sorry i din't understand your reply. do you mean is this wrong? what should be the correct one?

Comment: _I_ am sorry, just wanted to state that UTF-8 would be optimal, and evidently there is a conversion with a non-full (non-Unicode) encoding.